# io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented) while docker run with nginx

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, cloud

i'm migrating my angular app to cloud.

i build my image and when i run it i got this error

```
[emerg] 53#53: io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented)
```

this is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM artifactory.am.echonet/amcic-docker-local/node/amcic-node:14 as build
COPY . /application/test/
WORKDIR /application/test/
RUN ls -lrth
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 4200

FROM artifactory.am.echonet/digitalweb-docker-local/nginx:2.0.2
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

VOLUME type=tmpfs,destination=/var/cache/nginx/
VOLUME type=tmpfs,destination=/var/cache/nginx/
VOLUME type=tmpfs, destination=/var/run/
```

and this is my nginx.conf

```
events{}
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server {
        listen 4200;
        server_name localhost;
        root /application/test/;
        index index.html;
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

is there any solution/advice please?